# Передача строки из веб файла в переменную

Tags: godot

Пишу игру на Godot, мне потребовалась проверка на наличие новой версии игры. Т.е. игра обращается к файлу лежащему на сервере с примерно таким содержимым:

```
v1.23.1
```

Сохраняет эту строку в переменную и сравнивает с текущей версией, в случае несовпадения говорит, что можно загрузить новую версию.
У меня вопрос как реализовать получение этой строки. Пишу на GDScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё было очень просто.
Создаём ноду `HTTPRequest` и делаем запрос на сайт используя эту ноду

```
$HTTPRequest.request("https://site.com/somefile")
```

Привязываем функцию

```
func _on_HTTPRequest_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    SOME_TEXT = body.get_string_from_utf8() #Переменная с текстом файла
```

Вот и всё!